# Tests in Suggested Edits queue take to much to load

Tags: bug

Lately, when reviewing the Suggested Edits queue, sometimes it takes about 30-40 seconds to load the next question, staying a while at the `loading item ...` text.

[image: snapshot]

This only happens when the next question being loaded is a test and *only* at the Suggested Edits queue, and although this makes me be extra forewarned, I believe I don't deserve such a privilege!

I couldn't find anything related here. Is that a bug?

Comment: LOL. I've noticed that as well. I'm sure I seen the question before  It is a bit of a giveaway ;) Ah, here it is [Review - audit questions take longer to load?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198584)

Comment: Yep, I see. It doesn't seem to answer if this is a bug or whether it's intended, though :-/

Comment: Blasted tests.. ;)